# How do we conclude that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x/(1+x^2)dx$ is not convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

In computing the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx$ I get the following answers:

1. $0$ due to the symmetry of the integrand.
2. $\left.\ln(\sqrt{1+x^2})\right|_{-\infty}^\infty$ from brute force integration, with the $u$ substitution $u=x^2+1$.
3. $i\pi$ from the complex integral $$\oint_C\frac{z}{(z+i)(z-i)}dz = 2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{z}{z+i} = i\pi$$ where $C$ is semi-circular arc with a center at the origin and encloses the upper-half complex plane with radius $R\rightarrow \infty$.

Questions: How do we conclude that the integral is divergent? Is it due to the fact that we get different values of the integral? If so, is there any way we can make this conclusion without having to using all these different approaches? Is there some sort of uniqueness hypothesis for the integral?

Comment: The third option fails because, among other things, the arc contribution $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^\pi\frac{iR^2e^{2i\theta}d\theta}{1+R^2e^{2i\theta}}=i\pi$ can't be neglected.

Comment: @J.G. I see. So taking into consideration what you have pointed out, the 3rd option reduces to the first, i.e., $\oint \frac{f(z) dz}{z-i} = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{z dz}{1+z^2} + \int_{-R}^R\frac{x dx}{1+x^2}$, where $\Gamma$ is the semi-circular and $f(z) = \frac{z}{z+i}$. Which by Cauchy's integral formula and the integral you have computed we get $i\pi = \int_{-R}^R\frac{x dx}{1+x^2} + i\pi$. In the limit we then get 1.

Comment: I advise you to work through the contour-integral proof that $\int_{-R}^R\frac{xdx}{1+x^2}=0$ for finite $R$. You'll want to separately consider $R<\pi,\,R>\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral of a continuous$^1$ function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ may not be defined. However, the integral of $|f| : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is always defined, so long as you allow the value $\infty$. Indeed, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is only defined if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)| dx < \infty$. In this case, we say the integral converges; otherwise, it diverges.

So, to show your integral diverges, you need to show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| dx = \infty$. In your case, you can compute:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left| \frac{x}{1+x^2} \right| dx
\geq \int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx
\geq \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x^2} dx
= \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx
= \infty
$$

So, the integral diverges.

---

I should note a slight caveat. There exist integrals (most notably, the [Dirichlet integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral)) such that $\int_0^\infty |f(x)| dx = \infty$, but $\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t f(x) dx$ converges to some finite value $I$. Then some people may argue that the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ should be defined to be $I$, while others may argue that it is undefined. It depends on how you are defining your integral. But in your case, we don't have this issue.

---

(1: I'm assuming $f$ is continuous here. This isn't necessary, but you do usually need some regularity assumptions on $f$. But, that's a whole other topic.)

Comment: Insightful. Is the reason why a continuous function may not be integrable due to the possibility of either the negative and positive parts being infinite? Or is there another reason I may not be aware of? The story with the Dirichlet integral is quite interesting! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ThatoTsabone that's it. Improper integrals are limits of Riemann integrals which have a direction built into them (upper limit $b\to+\infty$, for instance). This allows for perhaps artificial cancellation between positive and negative parts of a function. This is akin to conditional convergence for series. This is part of the genesis of measure theory. The idea behind measure theory is that the value of the integral should not depend on how you set the integral up. This works if there is absolute integrability (see Riemann rearrangement theorem for why conditional convergence is very bad).

Comment: @CameronWilliams explained it well. For Lebesgue integration, "$f$ is not integrable" means "$\int |f| = \infty$" (either the negative or positive part is infinite). For Riemann integration, you have to work with a limit; the comparison to conditional convergence is very apt. I suppose my answer only addresses the Lebesgue version; I'm not as familiar with the conventions and tricks for Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 7):

If we define $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ as $\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_{-R}^R,$ your symmetry argument would work. Indeed, it would work to show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\,dx=0.$

But this definition has a problem. In particular, it would mean:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+a)\,dx$$ would depend on $a,$ so a simple substitution $u=x+a, du=dx,$ would not be allowed in $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}.$

In reality, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\lim_{(R_1,R_2)\to(+\infty,+\infty)}\int_{-R_2}^{R_1}$$

If one of $R_1,R_2$ goes to infinity much faster than the other, the limit of your integral is not zero.

In your case, $$\int_{-R_2}^{R_1}\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\ln\left(\frac{1+R_1^2}{1+R_2^2}\right)$$
If $R_1=cR_2$ for some positive constant $c,$ then $\lim_{R_2\to\infty}=2\ln(c).$

Even worse, if $R_1=R_2^2,$ the limit is $+\infty.$

---

In some sense, this is like a non-absolutely convergent series.

In particular, if $$\lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}|f(x)|\,dx<+\infty,$$ we get the easier limit $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} f(x)\,dx$$

---

Alternatively, we can define it as: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \int_{-\infty}^0+\int_{0}^{+\infty}.$$

This will give for your function a sum $(-\infty)+(+\infty),$ which is not defined.

Comment: I was unaware of the method where one sets the integration limits to different values before taking the limits. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @ThatoTsabone for general interest, the choice $\displaystyle\int_{-R}^R$ is a Cauchy principal value type regularization. It is in a similar vein to using contour integrals to evaluate the integral.

Comment: @CameronWilliams It all makes sense after I've taken into consideration the fact that the line integral over the arc does not vanish, as pointed out by J.G in the comments of the question. Thank you for the useful comments, hey!